# How come my <textarea> is not centered when it parents are centered with 'margin: 0 auto'?

Tags: css, html, textarea, center

For some reason my textarea DIV is not inheriting

```
margin: 0 auto
```

from its parent:

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a link to my [CSS & HTML for this example](http://gist.github.com/503132)

How can I make it so that the textarea DIV actually gets centered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to textarea style. After that textarea will be treated as block element and will be displayed centered.

```
textarea
{
    display:block;
        resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 460px;
    padding: 3px;   
}
```

Comment: You've brought me great joy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By default, margins are not inherited. You need to specifiy `margin: 0 auto;` explicitly for the textarea in question. Otherwise, the containing element will be centered, but the textarea will be laid out inside the container according to the regular flow (ie., `margin: 0;`).

Comment: actually 'margin: 0 auto' did get inherited by the #container, .reply-box and <form>. <textarea> was the only one that did not inherit it. look at @azram19 answer for it solved my problem.